# I have a problem with setting my init view controller once my users login once

Tags: ios, swift

I want to let my users not have to log in after they made a account. I linked my login and sign up view controllers to Firebase. The error I am running into is a caution error the says "Will never be executed" on the line `vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "loginVC")` can anyone help me with this please.

Here is the other code:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    FirebaseApp.configure()

    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main)
    let logined = true;
    var vc: UIViewController?
    if !logined {
        vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "loginVC")
        vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SignUpVC")
    } else {
        vc = storyboard.instantiateInitialViewController()
    }
    window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    window?.rootViewController = vc
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

  return true
}
```

Comment: Were you actually able to do the "login" part? You need to go back to the basics of everything. The error that says ```Will never be executed``` can be easily understood. You have a constant `logined`. How will that ever be changed to false? And from here, you should get the next explanation for your error.

Comment: @Glenn I can succesfully log in but I want to have to ability to skip the login screen once Ive done it once. So it changes the init view controller to my tabbed home screen automatically.

Comment: That's actually a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60784704/how-do-i-change-initial-view-controller-after-the-user-successfully-logs-in#comment107544024_60784704. As I said in your other question you have to **check** if the user is logged in.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of having the `logined` flag as a variable have it in [UserDefaults](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults) and update the value when required. On updating this way you can avoid **Will never be executed** warning in code.

**Example**

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main)
    let logined = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "logined")
    var vc: UIViewController?
    var window: UIWindow?

    if !logined {
        vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "loginVC")
        vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SignUpVC")
    } else {
        vc = storyboard.instantiateInitialViewController()
    }
    window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    window?.rootViewController = vc
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

**Set UserDefault Value:**

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "logined")
```

**Get UserDefault Value**

```
let logined = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "logined")
```

**Note:** UserDefault of type bool will return false when no value is set.

Answer (score 0):

If you use SceneDelegate just add this like:

```
var window: UIWindow?


func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
    guard let _ = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }


    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main)
    let logined = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "login")
    var vc: UIViewController?
    if logined {
        vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "loggedVC")
    }else{
        vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "loginVC")
    }
    window?.rootViewController = vc
    window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
}
```